# Static vs member functions in c++ is there an overhead

Tags: c++, static

In a C++ class is there any overhead in having static function instead of a member functions.

```
class CExample
{
    public: 
        int foo( int a, int b) {
            return a + b ; 
        }
        static int bar( int a, int b) {
            return a + b ; 
        } 
};
```

My questions are;

- In this example is foo() or bar() more effecent?.
- Why would I not want to make foo() in to a static function as it does not alter any member variables?

Comment: 3rd question: Why aren't both of those free functions?

Comment: Your compiler is probably smart enough to make these just as efficient as each other.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: The answer is that it does not matter, but the compiler cannot make them *exactly* the same, one has a hidden argument (`this`) that is not present in the other [The whole argument is assuming that the function is not *inlined* by the compiler]

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Assuming the implementation isn't inlined, I'd love to see the compiler which does not use the platform's equivalent of `thiscall` (i.e. wasting a register on a `this` pointer which is never used). There are better ways to argue that the difference never matters than claiming there is no difference, when it fast there is one.

Comment: @Xeo If `CExample` were a class template, then member functions would allow for easier partial specialization.

Comment: @rhalbersma: Not really, since you'd need to specialize the whole class. Partial specialization of function templates can easily be realized with overloading.

Comment: @Xeo it's the other way around: to simulate partial specialization of a function template, it's idiomatic to delegate to a function object template that is partially specialized. `CExample` could be such an inner class (with foo as helper function)

Comment: @rhalbersma: Sure, but that's totally different from here and I still think using overload resolution is better.

Comment: I wish someone would answer without assuming optimizations, it is clear this is a trivial example for the purpose of asking a question. I would like to know for example if both functions live in the same area of memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In this example is foo() or bar() more efficent?

No. Both calls are resolved statically. There may be some overhead in passing the `this` pointer to a non-`static` function, but in this case both will likely be inlined.

> Why would I not want to make foo() in to a static function as it does not alter any member variables?

You wouldn't, it's actually good practice to make all methods not bound to an instance `static`.

Comment: +1: Slight over-generalization with the last sentence but I agree with the sentiment you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 6):

This answer focuses addresses the second part of your question
Quoted from C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices:

> Chapter 44. Prefer writing nonmember nonfriend functions
>   [...] Nonmember nonfriend functions improve encapsulation by minimizing dependencies [...]

Scott Meyers proposes the following algorithm for determining which methods should be members of a class ([source](http://www.drdobbs.com/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197))

```
if (f needs to be virtual)
   make f a member function of C;
else if (f is operator>> or operator<<)
   {
   make f a non-member function;
   if (f needs access to non-public members of C)
      make f a friend of C;
   }
else if (f needs type conversions on its left-most argument)
   {
   make f a non-member function;
   if (f needs access to non-public members of C)
      make f a friend of C;
   }
else if (f can be implemented via C's public interface)
   make f a non-member function;
else
   make f a member function of C;
```

As for the first half of your question, I'd guess the compiler would optimize any difference away.

Answer (score 1):

bar MAY have less overhead in some compilers/situations since it will never need to be placed in a pointer table and will not need an extra "this" parameter.

the only reason to make foo non-static if it does not use local memebers is if you intend to overload it, but since it is not virtual this does not come into play.

Comment: Likely the compiler will optimize away refernece to "this". In all likelyhood a function this simple will get completely inlined.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista: That assumes that the function definition is visible to the compiler. You cannot in general assume that (at least not without making your assumptions explicit)

Comment: Many modern compilers do global optimization after link time to catch just this kind of thing.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista My last status was that LTO required *at least* explicitly passing an obscure flag, has a couple of issues, and is not nearly as awesome as it could be (read: only minor optimizations like dead code removal, not large deals like specializing whole call sub-graphs based on constant arguments from some call sites), and for these reasons is rarely used. Did I miss a memo?

Comment: You may be right. There is -flto and -fwhole-program in gcc. I don't think these are on by default. So this kind of optimization may not happen by default.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no difference, because neither function accesses data members, and you don't derive from anything virtual.

But in the general case "bar" would be infinitessimally faster because "foo" as member function normally has to pass and use an additional argument - "this"

Comment: By infinitessimally you mean non measurable. Even if there was an actual difference (given modern pipeline processors and modern calling conventions there may not be) this would never be measurable as there are so many other things that would drown out the difference.

Comment: -1 The this pointer will always be optimized away when no class specific data is being accessed. It's the same as any other non-referenced function argument.

Comment: Agreed. This is clearly a newbie question and I just wanted to illustrate the principle that all things being equal member functions require an additional argument and in principle as slightly more expensive.

Comment: @rhalberma: -1 to your comment for you lack of reading comprehension and pendantic foolishness. The first line of my answer is "there is no difference" for this exact reason.

Comment: @rhalberma: and another -1 for your lack of understanding of how compilers work. As David Rodriguez says below - in cases where the function definition is not visible to the compiler the this pointer is not optimized away. E.g. what if this function were defined in a dynamic library interface.